# If the polynomial $\det{(F − \lambda I)}$ has non-real zeros, then V has no basis consisting of eigenvectors of F.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand a proof where I encounter the following:

> We have $n = deg (\det{(F − \lambda I)}) = dimV$ . As shown, an eigenvector basis
> exists if and only if the sum of the geometric multiplicities of the distinct eigenvalues
> equals $n$. By the lemma, this cannot happen if $\det (F − \lambda I)$ has non-real zeros.

The lemma referenced is the following:

> Let $F$ be a linear transformation on a finite-dimensional space $V$ , and
> let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $F$. Then the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda$ is less than or equal to the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$.

How can it follow from this lemma that if the zeros of $\det{(F-\lambda I)}$ are non real that the sum of the geometric multiplicities of the distinct eigenvalues equal $n$? If we have non real roots, we have to account for their conjugates of course, but I don't see how that would affect anything.

Any help would be much appriciated!

Comment: The problem is missing some context, for scalars, $i-\lambda$ has a non real zero and $1$ is a basis for the reals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, it's important to remember that eigenvalues are real numbers, not complex numbers. One can consider complex eigenvalues of operators on real vector spaces by looking at the complexification of the operator, but this is not what the book is trying to do. Eigenvalues have to belong to the ground field $\Bbb{R}$, so that we get eigenvectors within the (real) space.

The geometric multiplicity of eigenvalue $\lambda_0$ is the dimension of the (not generalised) eigenspace, i.e. $\ker (\lambda_0 I - F)$. The algebraic multiplicity is the power of $\lambda - \lambda_0$ in the characteristic polynomial.

If the sum of geometric multiplicities is $n$, by the lemma, then the sum of the algebraic multiplicities is at least $n$. So, $\det(\lambda I - F)$ has factors of the form $(\lambda - \lambda_k)^{\alpha_k}$ where the sum of the $\alpha_k$s is at least $n$. This puts the degree of $\det(\lambda I - F)$ at at least $n$.

But, as you and the book know, the characteristic polynomial has degree exactly $n$. If even one algebraic multiplicity were strictly greater than the geometric multiplicity, then we would have a degree strictly greater than $n$.

This also means that the factors $(\lambda - \lambda_k)^{\alpha_k}$, where $\lambda_k$ is a (real) eigenvalue and $\alpha_k$ is its geometric/algebraic multiplicity, are the only factors of the characteristic polynomial. There can't be any irreducible quadratic factors (i.e. complex roots), because we have the total of $n$ degrees provided by linear factors.